# Wrapping text inside div1 around div2 that is positioned right in the middle of its parent using CSS only

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

This is what I have in mind:
[image]
and I would like to know the simplest way to achieve this purely in CSS adding as little rigidity as possible.

I know it's easy to use float to push the red div left or right. It's also possible to do background on the blue div and simply center the red one as if the blue was empty.

But I need the text to wrap neatly around the red box, and I can also specify the exact dimensions of both boxes if needed.

Comment: Not possible with CSS

Comment: I've seen some more or less hacky solutions to make text appear to be flowing around an image/other element on both sides - but those usually require that the text gets split into multiple elements. (Plus, they don't _continue_ the text flow on either side, it is more like a two-column text layout as you would find in a newspaper.) A solution where you just slap a bit of CSS onto an existing structure and get this working for whatever dynamic texts, does not exist.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.